# When reusing reusable components in React, we want to avoid runtime exceptions caused by the implementer as much as possible

Tags: reactjs, typescript

#### Assumptions

I am implementing the following components using TypeScript and React.

- Contains code to fetch data from the server (executes a Web API)
- If the API is executed by a user other than the user with the Admin role (e.g., Member role), the data fetch will fail and an exception will be raised.

```
export const ShowDataComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<Data>(undefined);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDataArrowAccessAdminUser().then((data) => setData(data));
  }, []);

  return <>{data && <div>data</div>}</>;
};
```

#### Problem

The trouble I personally see with this code is,

If this component is reused by another developer and implemented on a page that is visible to users in roles other than Admin, a runtime exception will always be thrown (if the component was tested only with users in the Admin role, it will always throw an exception when accessed with the Member role). (If you were only testing with users in the Admin role, you could end up releasing code that will always throw an exception when accessed with the Member role).

I believe that this is the case.

I have personally solved the above problem by implementing the following.

```
type Props = {
  userRole: "admin";
};

export const ShowDataComponent = (props: Props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<Data>(undefined);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDataArrowAccessAdminUser().then((data) => setData(data));
  }, []);

  return <>{data && <div>data</div>}</>;
};
```

However, I don't like this implementation a little bit because it passes props that are not used at all.

The `userRole` is only used to cause a compile error, but when other developers only see the type definition of the props and use that component, it should only be implemented on pages where the userRole is only visible to people in the Admin role (or I can make it explicit that a condition must be added before rendering the component, such as `userRole.admin && (<ShowDataComponent userRole={userRole.admin} />`).

In that sense, I think it's a good solution there, because developers who reuse this component will realize that they are using it improperly at compile time when they use it improperly.

If anyone can think of a solution other than my solution, please let me know.

Comment: Does adding a `.catch()` not handle the exception?

Comment: Yes, you can handle exceptions by adding a catch clause.
But that's not what I want to argue here.

Even if you can handle the exception, if a developer other than you reuses the component in a page that only users in the Memer role can see, the exception will always occur on that page.
Of course, by adding a `.catch()`, you can always catch exceptions, render error components, etc.

However, I don't think it will be what end users want.

As much as possible, I would like to detect inappropriately used components at the timing of tsc, npm run build, etc.

Comment: Perhaps then it's less an issue of trying to produce a compiler error and more an issue of the naming and clarity of what the component does in the first place.  If a developer is working on functionality strictly for one role and uses a component that's intended strictly for another role, that begs the question... What does that developer *think* the component does and why?  Perhaps that intent just needs to be more clearly indicated in the naming and documentation for the component...

Comment: ...There's always a chance the developer simply isn't paying attention to what they're doing or just doesn't bother even trying to understand the tools they're using.  I doubt there's a guaranteed way to prevent that.  But that's not so much a technical problem to be solved in the code.  In those cases the component should just have stable runtime behavior, to include any reasonable output or warnings/errors.